# Why Selector Not Calling in swift

Tags: swift, selector

I am  calling through my view controller like:

```
Util().nav(self.navigationItem)
```

And Class is:

```
class Util: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Initialization
    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    func nav(navigationItem: UINavigationItem){
        let leftBackArrow = UIBarButtonItem(title: "A", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backPress:")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBackArrow;
        leftBackArrow.image = UIImage(named: "nav_back")
    }

    func backPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("HI")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem. Note that ARC needs to see a strong reference to your Utils object. But in this case, what is happening is, you are instantiating and calling a method on it. But ARC will think that this object can go once the control from the scope where this is defined comes out and it will release the temporary Utils object that is being created. This is the reason why your action will be never called.

To fix this, instead of having the functions as member functions, make them class functions-

```
class Util: NSObject {

class func nav(navigationItem: UINavigationItem){
    let leftBackArrow = UIBarButtonItem(title: "A", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backPress:")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBackArrow;
    leftBackArrow.image = UIImage(named: "nav_back")
}

class func backPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    print("HI")
}
}
```

And now you can use it as:

```
Util.nav(self.navigationItem)
```

HTH